# Datastucture for random

Tags: node.js

I want to random pick an item from a list. This is no problem, but the size is worrying me.

I have a sort of lottery game where a user can buy one or multiple tickets. Each ticket is a chance to win. I need to draw some players from the list.

So I thought I am going to build a list like:

```
//loop over all the players
for loop
   get the number of tickets
      loop over the number of tickets
        insert the user x times into an array
```

So when the user has 10 tickets, he is going to saved 10x in the array. So I can randomly draw someone from that list. But the problem is, I have around 1600 users with each 200k tickets or more.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Number each ticket, pick a random number?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a json object as

```
{ "players" : [ { "player": id , "ticketsNu" : num } .... ]
  "totalNu" : numb }
```

When it comes to choosing the winning ticket, then you have to calculate each players chances as

```
players.forEach((player)=>{ player.chances = player.tiketsNu / players.totalNu })
```